# Reading images from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am reading data from xml and setting it to `EditText` view. Here data contains images also.
I am able to display data in EditText view using html.fromHtml() method.

The problem is when I am get data from EditText and store it in a string I am not getting images when I set that string to another TextView.
I am reading using

```
  string s=editextview.gettext();
```

Comment: Your question just baffled me. if you are trying to transfer an image in a string, convert the image to base64String. THen back again on the other side.

Comment: how you are able too display data in EditText? Whats the data?

Comment: Are you getting a line like <img src="url" alt="some_text"/> and want to display that? If so, that gets complicated. You might have to update your mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got your question. If you are trying to read a xml document containg both text and images (such as a HTML file), determine how many images you  have. Have as many ImageView in your layout as are the number of images in xml (adding it dynamically). Display text in EditText or Text View (depending on how you want it). You will have to format it.

AS far as i know, you can not display images in EditText view.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) instead. It'll allow you to display your text and images as well independent of the layout.

Comment: I tried using webview. But with webview when I try to show long html data with images it is giving error"page can not find". But it is working if html contains one images and less data. I am not understanding why it is giving error for huge data. Cant webview support huge data?